# How gdb runs without capabilities?

Tags: gdb, linux-capabilities

I'm trying to understand why gdb is able to debug a process even if it runs without capabilities.

My non-root user has the following configuration:

```
$ /sbin/capsh --print
Current: =
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=1000(test)
gid=1000(test)
groups=1000(test)
```

GDB hasn't any capability activated

```
$ /sbin/getcap /usr/bin/gdb
$
```

But I'm able to debug a process, set a breakpoint and so on.

I thought gdb needed

> cap_sys_ptrace

at least in order to work correcly, but seems I'm wrong.
Can you explain me why I'm able to debug a process?

Comment: Do you have a `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` file?

Comment: I've totally missed `ptrace_scope` file: I've changed its value to `2` and now I'm not able to debug a running process but I'm still able to debug a program `gdb myfile`. Why?

Comment: Another question: `ptrace_scope` overrides my capability. Do you know other kernel parameter able to override a capability?

Comment: About the first comment: why I'm still able to debug a program if I use the command `gdb myfile`?

Comment: About the second comment: I was not aware about kernel parameters able to override Linux capabilities. I have a question about this point: how can I be sure my capabilities are not overridden by some kernel parameters configuration? My final goal is to check every capability for a binary...Do you know a test case able to identify if a generic capability is overridden or not?

Comment: When you `gdb myfile` are you actually running the program?  gdb doesn't use `ptrace` until the inferior is launched.